# Add onclick listener to Google Maps Markers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var address = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonLocations ?>');
    console.log(address.locations[0]);
    var latitude = '1';
    var longitude = '1';

    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
        });
        for(var i = 0; i < address.locations.length; i++){

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(address.locations[i]['lat'], address.locations[i]['long']),
                map: map
            }).addListener('click', function(){
                new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h5>' + i +'</h5>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'
                }).open(map, this);
            })
        }
    }

</script>
```

I'm trying to display `i` onClick of the marker. So for the first maker I should be 0 and for the second 1. But somehow `i` is always the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic closure problem.
The function which is using the `i` variable is a async callback.

The first thing what is happening is, that all the markers will be created. Therefore `i` will be `address.locations.length` at the end of the loop.
The async callbacks now reference this exact variable.

There are some possible fixes for this:

use the let statement if you are able to use ES6 JavaScript features:

```
for(let i = 0; i < address.locations.length; i++){
    [...]
}
```

The second one is to create a closure with this exact binding:

```
for(var i = 0; i < address.locations.length; i++){
    (function(i){
        [...]
    })(i)
}
```

The last option for you is to use the `Function.bind` method.

```
for(var i = 0; i < address.locations.length; i++){

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(address.locations[i]['lat'], address.locations[i]['long']),
        map: map
    }).addListener('click', (function(i){
        new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h5>' + i +'</h5>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>'
        }).open(map, this);
    }).bind(this,i))
}
```

I hope that one of this methods will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the click event happens later in time and then `i` has the last value ...

To fix this you can use a self invoking anonymous function inside the `for` loop - this way you will create a scope for each loop and the value of `i` will remain for the `click` when it happens.

This is called Closure - you can read more about closures [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)

```js
function initMap() {

  var address = {
    locations: [{
      "lat": 30.53625,
      "lng": -111.92674,
    }, {
      "lat": 33.53625,
      "lng": -112.92674,
    }, {
      "lat": 32.53625,
      "lng": -111.92674,
    }, {
      "lat": 33.53625,
      "lng": -115.92674,
    }]
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.53625, -111.92674)
  });
  var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < address.locations.length; i++) {

    (function(index) { /* <--- Self invoking function */
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(address.locations[index]['lat'], address.locations[index]['lng']),
        map: map
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h5>' + index + '</h5>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        }).open(map, this);

        markers.push(marker);
      });
    })(i); /* <---- Pass the index to the closure to keep its value */
  }

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:150px"></div>
```

Comment: @SanderBakker I was seeing then in Firefox but yes when tried to see them in IE and Chrome - they was not working. Now fixed it, sorry for that. Just refresh the page and everything appears, but with a small delay because it is async